# list dependencies of pkgbuild with shell script

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, aur, pkgbuild

How can I list dependencies of a `PKGBUILD` file with shell script?

For example, in a [`google-chrome`'s `PKGBUILD`](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=google-chrome), I want the script to extract all dependencies (including `makedependencies`, `dependencies` and `optdependencies`) like this:

```
alsa-lib
gtk3
libcups
libxss
libxtst
nss
kdialog
...
```

I think this can be achieved with regex, but I don't know how...

Comment: Well, regex certainly won't work. A PKGBUILD is bash, the dependency arrays can contain anything including references to other variables or simply execute a program to find out the contents. In general, it's not a good idea to walk into a question with assumptions about what you expect the answer to involve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PKGBUILD is already a bash script. You could `source` it, but that is dangerously insecure.

Instead, the [.SRCINFO](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/.SRCINFO) file was created, which is supposed to be parseable as a key-value file. You could use for example the "python-srcinfo" package to parse this in Python -- it is what we use as part of the https://aur.archlinux.org website itself. Alternatively, you could use awk from within bash for this -- one popular AUR helper, aurutils, uses this awk script to do .SRCINFO parsing: https://github.com/AladW/aurutils/blob/master/lib/aur-graph